# iUI: Back button doesn't work in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, iui

I have a mixed web/native app, and I use a (you guessed it) UIWebView to display the html portion of the app. Do to the nature of the app, I am using the view without any toolbar, including forward/back buttons.

The html is designed using iUI. All of the "pages" are contained in the same document using ids to designate page content. When viewing the html on the iPhone in safari, iUI's 'backbutton' works as intended. However, when I use the html in UIWebView, iUI's 'backbutton' doesn't work.

Is there a something I'm missing, either in iUI, or what's more likely, in UIWebView to get the 'backbutton' to work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over to jQTouch, which is a much nicer library, and even though it's still beta, it was relatively a snap to work with. Best of all, it look a lot snazzier too! Good job jQTouch team!